# How do windshear warning systems work?

Tags: landing

How do commercial aircraft windshear alert  warning systems work?

Comment: Do you mean Wind Shear? If you do, ATC may warn you of it if they are aware of it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Modern commercial airliners have 2 different wind shear protection system:
1) predictive wind shear warning system
2) reactive wind shear warning system.

These systems work independently. PWS (predictive wind shear) works with weather radar. Reactive wind shear works with FAC ( Flight augmentation computer)

Basicly PWS can be switched ON and OFF from the WX-Radar  panel and it has some prerequisite for working : 
Ground speed should be above 30 KTS, WX-Radar should be ON, At least one engine working etc. (may differ with different types).

PWS scans 5 NM ahead from 0-2300 ft and 1500 ft below according to phase of the flight. It works like a doppler radar. It scans the movement of air mass in front of you and "predicts" something goes wrong and warns you according to how bad is the situation. Doppler frequency will shift significantly in case of a microburst so PWS will catch this shift and warn pilots with amber or red cautions.

Reactive Wind shear system works with on board computers that takes real time data from all sources. This system will be active generally from 50 ft 1300 ft. (may differ)

Reactive Wind Shear basiclly monitors aircrafts energy level. For Airbus; FAC is responsible for that. 
In computing the energy level FACs use different data from different sources: ADIRS - air, ground speed, vertical speed , slope. from other sources - wind gradient, vertical wind etc.

It will be active when the a/c energy level goes below predetermined threshold. It will alter from amber to red if your energy losing trend is faster.

You can read this document from airbus includes many general aviation information for more details : 
http://www.airbus.com/fileadmin/media_gallery/files/safety_library_items/AirbusSafetyLib_-FLT_OPS-ADV_WX-SEQ02.pdf

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Wind shear warning systems essentially augment the pitot-static system with a radar altimeter and/or GPS. The system bounces radar waves off the ground beneath it to get a true AGL altitude. The system also knows the topology of the region if it's given a GPS fix (GPS can also indicate AGL altitude but it's less precise than a radar altimeter). The warning will sound when the radar altimeter indicates a change in descent rate that isn't matched by the pitot-static system (the VSI will either indicate no change or it will be erratic, as the plane is essentially flying straight and level through a downward-moving mass of air), and not accounted for by known ground elevation changes. This same system can also warn of any dangerous descent rate (descending below a threshold altitude with gear up, at too high a speed, at too great a rate for landing, etc).

Comment: Wind shear is not always associated with a downward air mass.  It can also be a simple reversal of direction, or a marked change in speed at a particular level.  In this case, this system does not help.  Of course, the ASI will warn an attentive pilot and more modern weather RADARs use Doppler effects to measure and warn of wind shear.

Comment: @Simon - I don't disagree, but the most dangerous form of wind shear to an aircraft is a downdraft, for the simple reason that it pushes the aircraft toward the ground. A severe "downburst" is doubly dangerous because not only is the downward wind speed extremely strong, they usually happen in instrument conditions so visual cues that the aircraft is sinking too fast are sparse.